# Guidance with import/export with Magento

Tags: excel, magento

With magento import sheet are you able to move things around or do the rows and columns have to remain in the same place for database reasons?

the reason i ask is that i have to run some exports and drag data out of bits here and there and its a bit of a pain moving around the sheet.

example:
Export sheet:  Name / SKU / Image / Price
Import:        Name / SKU / Image / Price -> then have the rest continue here.

Comment: you can use magmi : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Default Magento import has got  very strict requirements to structure of the file.

Columns can be sorted in any position, however, you have to stick to the list of required for import columns (their headings have to be the same as database names) and values in them. You can check mandatory import fields and details within them.

Moreover, sometimes even negatively exported file does not suit to import it back. Editing the file you have to make sure that it is re-saved with UTF-8 without BOM encoding.